# tdbloader on Cygwin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: windows, cygwin, jena, classnotfoundexception, tdbloader

I'm trying to use tbdloader on Cygwin (Windows 7 with the latest Java installation). This is the tbdloader documentation: http://jenawiki.hpl.hp.com/wiki/TDB/Commands

This is the wrapper script I'm using to call tdbloader on my machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Cygwin script to import large NT files in TDB.

CD /cygdrive/c/mypath/TDB-0.8.10
echo "TDB found. Setting path"
export TDBROOT=/cygdrive/c/mypath/TDB-0.8.10
export PATH=$PATH:$TDBROOT/bin

CD /cygdrive/c/mypath/ontodata/
echo "Running import..."
tdbloader --loc ./tdb ./datasets/large_file.nt
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tdb/tdbloader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tdb.tdbloader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: tdb.tdbloader.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

The tdbloader works fine on Mac and Linux.

Any ideas?

Mulone

Comment: Does tdbloader work outside your script? Try adding `echo $TDB_CP` just before the exec java line, to check the classpath has been set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already mentioned to you in another answer, the issue is the `:` and `;` classpath separators in Linux and Windows respectively. See [this FAQ](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/faq/) for details, which suggests you should adapt the script to include `cygpath`.