# tdbloader on Cygwin: Gettging FileNotFoundException: d:\cygdrive\d\....\node2id.idn

Tags: java, jena

I am completely new to Jena/TDB. All I want to do is to load data from some sample rdf, N3 etc file using tdb scripts or through java api. 
I am tried to use `tbdloader` on Cygwin to load data (tdb-0.9.0, on Windows XP with IBM Java 1.6). Following are the command that I ran:

```
$ export TDBROOT=/cygdrive/d/Project/Store_DB/jena-tdb-0.9.0-incubating
$ export PATH=$TDBROOT/bin:$PATH
```

I also changed *classpath* for java in the *tdbloader script* as mentioned at [tdbloader on Cygwin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089278/tdbloader-on-cygwin-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) :

```
exec java $JVM_ARGS $SOCKS -cp "PATH_OF_JAR_FILES" "tdb.$TDB_CMD" $TDB_SPEC "$@"
```

So when I run `$ tdbloader --help` it shows the help correctly.
But when I run

```
$ tdbloader --loc /cygdrive/d/Project/Store_DB/data1
```

OR

```
$ tdbloader --loc /cygdrive/d/Project/Store_DB/data1 test.rdf
```

I am getting following exception:

```
        com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: Failed to open: d:\cygdrive\d\Project\Store_DB\data1\node2id.idn (mode=rw)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.ChannelManager.open$(ChannelManager.java:83)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.ChannelManager.openref$(ChannelManager.java:58)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.ChannelManager.acquire(ChannelManager.java:47)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.FileBase.<init>(FileBase.java:57)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.FileBase.<init>(FileBase.java:46)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.FileBase.create(FileBase.java:41)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.BlockAccessBase.<init>(BlockAccessBase.java:46)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.block.BlockMgrFactory.createStdFile(BlockMgrFactory.java:98)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.block.BlockMgrFactory.createFile(BlockMgrFactory.java:82)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.block.BlockMgrFactory.create(BlockMgrFactory.java:58)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.Builder$BlockMgrBuilderStd.buildBlockMgr(Builder.java:196)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.Builder$RangeIndexBuilderStd.createBPTree(Builder.java:165)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.Builder$RangeIndexBuilderStd.buildRangeIndex(Builder.java:134)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.Builder$IndexBuilderStd.buildIndex(Builder.java:112)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.Builder$NodeTableBuilderStd.buildNodeTable(Builder.java:85)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd$NodeTableBuilderRecorder.buildNodeTable(DatasetBuilderStd.java:389)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.makeNodeTable(DatasetBuilderStd.java:300)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd._build(DatasetBuilderStd.java:167)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.build(DatasetBuilderStd.java:157)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.build(DatasetBuilderStd.java:70)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.StoreConnection.make(StoreConnection.java:132)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction.DatasetGraphTransaction.<init>(DatasetGraphTransaction.java:46)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMakerTxn._create(TDBMakerTxn.java:50)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMakerTxn.createDatasetGraph(TDBMakerTxn.java:38)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory._createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:166)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:74)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDataset(TDBFactory.java:53)
        at tdb.cmdline.ModTDBDataset.createDataset(ModTDBDataset.java:95)
        at arq.cmdline.ModDataset.getDataset(ModDataset.java:34)
        at tdb.cmdline.CmdTDB.getDataset(CmdTDB.java:137)
        at tdb.cmdline.CmdTDB.getDatasetGraph(CmdTDB.java:126)
        at tdb.cmdline.CmdTDB.getDatasetGraphTDB(CmdTDB.java:131)
        at tdb.tdbloader.loadQuads(tdbloader.java:163)
        at tdb.tdbloader.exec(tdbloader.java:122)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:97)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:59)
        at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:46)
        at tdb.tdbloader.main(tdbloader.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\cygdrive\d\Project\Store_DB\data1\node2id.idn (The system cannot find the path specified.)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:222)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:107)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.ChannelManager.open$(ChannelManager.java:80)
        ... 37 more
```

I am not sure what *node2id.idn* file is and why is it expecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `node2id.idn` is one of TDB's internal index files. It's not something that you have to create or manage for yourself. I've just tried `tdbloader` on cygwin myself, it it worked OK for me. I can think of two basic possibilities:

- your disk is full
- the TDB index is corrupted

If this is the first file you are loading into an otherwise emtpy TDB, the second possibility is unlikely. If you are loading into a non-empty TDB, try deleting the TDB image and starting again. Note that TDB by itself does not manage concurrent writes: if you have more than one process writing to a single TDB image, you must handle locking at the application level, or use TDB's [transactions](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html).

The final possibility, of course, is that your disk is flaky. You might want to try your code on another machine.

If none of these suggestions help, please send a complete minimal test case to the Jena users list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By empty TDB, you mean directory `/cygdrive/d/Project/Store_DB/data1` is empty? yes, it is empty. My disk is also not full. So now I will try to run it on another machine, as you suggested.

Comment: Moved on to using Jena API(through code) to do this. Thanks for your help @IanDickinson.